I can query Athena in AWS console, but failed via Python
I can query Athena in AWS console. But when I query Athena using below python code,
client = boto3.client("Athena", 
    aws_access_key_id="ABCD1234",
    aws_secret_access_key="dcba4321987",
    region_name="us-west-2")

query = "SELECT count(*) FROM 'database'.'tableCCC' "
response = client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString=query,
        ResultConfiguration={"OutputLocation": "s3://test_bucket/test"}
    )

(source: https://www.learnaws.org/2022/01/16/aws-athena-boto3-guide/, )
I go the errors:
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) 
when calling the StartQueryExecution operation: You are not authorized to perform:  
athena:StartQueryExecution on the resource. 
After your AWS administrator or you have updated your permissions, please try again.

I am sure I used the correct credential and looked up relevant materials but no good luck. What else I still missed here? Thanks!


JIC - try lowercasing the resource name - 'athena' (though based on error it should not matter) 2. how did you get those credentials, are they "temporary" ones?



Check that you have appropriate permissions like athena:StartQueryExecution etc. and access to corresponding folders - see example here

